# Standard deviation of LN transformed value

Tags: data-transformation, standard-deviation, logarithm

So I have a set of experimentally-determined values (inhibition constants) that are given with their respective standard deviations. I used these values to calculate the free energy via the following formula:

```r
free energy = R * T * ln (inhibition constant)
```

I want to also transform the standard deviations. My question is how do I do that - it seems to me that just plugging the st. deviations in the above formula is not OK.

More specifically:

```r
Ki = 2.32 +- 0.095 uM
```

```r
G = R*T*ln(Ki) = 1.9872 * 0.001 * 303.15 * ln (2.32*10E-6) = -7.8 kcal/mol +- ?????
```

Answer (score 4):

To get to an **approximate** solution, you can use this rule:

$$
\sigma_{f(x)} \approx \left|\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right| \cdot \sigma(x)
$$

and then $\sigma(c f(x)) = c \cdot \sigma_{f(x)}$.

This comes from the first term of the Taylor expansion given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_expansions_for_the_moments_of_functions_of_random_variables#Second_moment).

It's very old now, but when I was first learning this stuff I found Lyons (1991) very clear and approachable.

In comments, @whuber says:

> Lognormal distributions are notorious: unless you are absolutely sure the distribution is lognormal, and you have a large amount of data, this approximation could be [...] way off. A good check is to inspect the estimated geometric s.d. Still assuming large amounts of data (hundreds or more), if the gsd is less than 0.3 or so, this approach is probably okay. If the gsd exceeds 0.5 or so, be cautious; and if it exceeds 1, the results [are] likely very unreliable.

These suggestions may not be feasible if you don't have access to the original data any more, or to summary information other than the standard deviation on the non-log-scale ...

---

Lyons, Louis. 1991. A Practical Guide to Data Analysis for Physical Science Students. Cambridge University Press.

Comment: (need abs value on derivative)

Comment: Good catch, thanks.

Comment: Lognormal distributions are notorious: unless you are *absolutely sure* the distribution is lognormal, *and* you have a large amount of data, this approximation could be hugely way off.  A good check is to inspect the estimated geometric s.d.  Still assuming large amounts of data (hundreds or more), if the gsd is less than 0.3 or so, this approach is probably okay.  If the gsd exceeds 0.5 or so, be cautious; and if it exceeds 1, the results a likely very unreliable.  These considerations suggest not transforming the SD at all, but staying with logarithms to report results.

Comment: I don't disagree with any of this (a reference would be useful), but it's not clear how you can get away without transforming the SD if you have the SDs on Ki scale but you need to compute in terms of ln(Ki) ?

Comment: @Ben There's a large literature on lognormals, especially among geostatisticians and environmental statisticians; but the suggestions in my comment are based on my own experience.  What this suggests is that using an SD to describe the variability of Ki might be misleading: something else is needed--such as describing the variability of its logarithm.

Comment: Right, but it's not clear whether OP has access to that ...